# How can I get 1 year multiple visa for Vietnam?

Tags: visas, vietnam

How much do you have to pay for 3 month extension visa within Vietnam? I'm in Hanoi now & getting tired of doing visa extension every 3 month at unacceptable price. I call several agents and they quoted me more than US$300 for 3 month. What's a f**king price!Heard of 1 year visa? Is it possible to get it on arrival? Any information would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Multiple entry visas are normally issued by the Vietnam Embassy in your home country or country of residence.  Once you are in the country, you are limited to extensions only, afaik

Answer (score 1):

There is no 1 year visa on arrival friend. You have to collect it directly at the embassy. You make application online through an agent and they will arrange a visa approval for you. You then carry the letter to embassy, pay some stamping fee and get your visa stamp. That's the process. Source: http://www.vietnamvisa-easy.com/pages/vietnam-business-visa

Answer (score -1):

If you hold US passport, you can apply for 1 year multiple entry visa on arrival. However, with 1 year multiple entry TOURIST visa you can stay in Vietnam for 90 days each visit then you will need to do visa run or visa extension.
1 year multiple entry BUSINESS visa give you permission to stay in the country 1 year continuously.
http://www.visumvietnamonline.com/blog/vietnam-1-year-tourist-visa-for-united-states-citizens-from-august-2016/

Comment: If you work for this company, please disclose your affiliation.